# Vue - justifying text to the right inside a row

Tags: vue.js

I'm having some trouble formatting text properly inside rows.

Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

And the code which produces that result:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center py-lg-4">
  <div class="col-circle-width order-lg-2">
    <i class="icon-heart large-circle-dati"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 d-block d-sm-none"></div>
  <div class="col-auto col-lg-3 order-lg-1 main-text-right">
    <div class="text-center text-sm-left text-lg-right">
      <strong>Top Text</strong>
      <p>Bottom Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-circle-width d-none d-lg-block order-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="w-100 d-lg-none p-3"></div>
  
  <div class="col-circle-width order-lg-4">
    <i class="icon-heart large-circle-dati"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="w-100 d-block d-sm-none"></div>
  <div class="col-auto col-lg-3 order-lg-5 main-text-left">
    <div class="text-center text-sm-left">
      <strong>Boreal Text</strong>
      <p>Austral Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 d-lg-none p-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center py-lg-4">
  <div class="col-circle-width order-lg-2">
    <i class="icon-heart large-circle-dati"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 d-block d-sm-none"></div>
  <div class="col-auto col-lg-3 order-lg-1 main-text-right">
    <div class="text-center text-sm-left text-lg-right">
      <strong>Septentrional Text</strong>
      <p>Meridional Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-circle-width d-none d-lg-block order-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="w-100 d-lg-none p-3"></div>
  <div class="col-circle-width order-lg-4">
    <i class="icon-heart large-circle-dati"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 d-block d-sm-none"></div>
  <div class="col-auto col-lg-3 order-lg-5 main-text-left">
    <div class="text-center text-sm-left">
      <strong>Northern Text</strong>
      <p>Southern Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 d-lg-none p-3"></div>
</div>
```

I've been trying to get the text to the left to be aligned with the icons - as displayed on the columns on the right - but can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any chance to have a working fiddle of the code?

Comment: @Raffobaffo I think that'd leave the code a bit too cluttered, but the only things wrapping the code in the question are a `template`, a `<div class=animated fadeIn>` and a plain old `div` :)

Comment: What if you push this column: <div class="col-auto col-lg-3 order-lg-1 main-text-right">
    <div class="text-center text-sm-left text-lg-right">
      <strong>Top Text</strong>
      <p>Bottom Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

to the right using margin-left: auto?

Comment: For some reason `:style="{margin-left: 'auto'}"` isn't valid syntax, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Just `style="margin-left: auto;"` would work. I don't know if it will fix your problem, but thats the correct syntax :)

Comment: Ahh, it didn't - thank you though!